# Confused with ssh - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: openssh

How do i correctly setup open-ssh on Debian. I had it all working - logging in using an authentication key (PasswordAuthentication set to no) then suddenly i get a *Permission denied (publickey)*. So i uninstalled ssh on the server and the remote client. Then got myself in a mess - the reinstall failed to set up .ssh directories in root or user level.

**History:**

I installed open-ssh on my server - as root
I installed open-ssh on my remote client pc - as root

I generated my public and private key on my server - as root.
I generated my public and private key on my remote pc - as root

I created an autorized key file in the .ssh directory on my server - as a user - and copied in my remote pc' public key

I mod'd my ssh config file to not allow password login

**My questions:**

Must you always install open-ssh as root?

If so does this then propagate down to all users giving them permission to accept an ssh connection?

Do you create the authorized key file as root or at user level?

I uninstalled everything* with `apt-get purge openssh-client` but it left .ssh directories allover the place. Is this usual practice on Linux and is it ok to just delete these leftover directories manually?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing a few elements in your understanding -

Practically you do need to install open ssh as root - by default it talks on port 22 which is restricted to root. You could probably set it up to answer on a non standard port above 1024 (normally 2222).

ssh does not "propogate down" - it runs as a daemon.   It will, however normally look in users home directories for ~user/.ssh/authorised_keys

You would typically create an authorised_keys file for each user on the system.    Note that the SSH server also has its own keys, which can usually be found in /etc/sshd

If there is nothing except SSH stuff you don't need its safe to delete the .ssh keys in the home directories manually.   Its also OK to leave them, because the client and server are 2 different things, but both use the same directory in some instances.

**Key handling -**

You would generally create a private and public key on your client, then add the public key to your server in ~user/.ssh/authorized_keys - You do not need to generate a private or public key on the server for the user - unless you additionally want that user to use the server as an ssh client.

Keys would generally be owned by the user who they belong to, and private keys would have a permission of 600.   You can also have the keys owned by root, but that will prevent the user from changing them.

Comment: thanks very much. With your help i managed to check everything and work out that the issue was with the permission settings of my authorized.keys (user level) directory. I used the following to set it correctly: 

chmod go-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys